# Dynamic pointer reference array return value by a ternary operator with exception

Tags: c++

I am learning about pointers, references, return values, and ternary operators.

I am trying to use a ***pointer to reference*** correctly for a dynamic array through the use of the parameter `int *&A`, without returning a newly created array. I strictly want to copy the array from the main loop, and set the size, if it fails to allocate throw an error.

Is this the correct way to go about this:

```
int
*_resize(int *&A, int s)
{
  try {
      return A = new int[s] == (nullptr) ? throw std::bad_alloc() : A;
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "H" << std::endl;
  }

}
int main()
{
  int *A;
  A = _resize (A, 1000000005546456456ul); // Test
}
```

Should I be using `(std::nothrow)` also:

```
return A = new (std::nothrow) int[s]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply?:

```
#include <iostream>
int *allocate(int s) noexcept
try { return new int[s]; } 
catch (...) { std::cout << "H" << std::endl; return nullptr; }

int main() {
    int *A = allocate (10000); 
    //(printing from utility functions and not using RAII
    //aren't exactly the C++ way)
}
```

Naming a function with a name starting with and underscore is undefined behavior.

Passing 1000000005546456456ul would convert to `int` in an implementation defined way, probably into `-235129464`, which would then convert into a very large `std::size_t` (probably either 4059837832 or 18446744073474422152). Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I am new to the language. And was trying to do something similar to your example with a ternary operator.

Comment: @Raymond C++ is a huge language and if you break the rules, it's undefined behavior, which means *anything* can happen (including files getting deleted). It's in your best interest to keep things as simple and clean as possible.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and appreciate your response. I am going to mark this as an acceptable answer. If you read my comment to Igor Tandetnik, I explained possibly more in-depth to what I was attempting. Thanks for working with me, this is very close to what I was trying to do without the ternary operator. You sound exactly like my professor.

Comment: If you wanted to either return or throw `std::bad_alloc()` you're basically doing what the new operator does, so: `int *allocate(int s){ return new[s]; }`. I'm calling it allocate because it doesn't resize anything.

Comment: what you coded made sense, as you said it was simpler. I am going to experiment and look up your use of `noexcept` and how you used `try` also in the function declaration, I did not know you were allowed to implement that. I am going to try and implement this with a ternary operator. Thank you

Comment: I was also using `if (A = nullptr)` to confirm if the size was allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = new int[s] == (nullptr) ? throw std::bad_alloc() : A;
```

makes little sense. Operator precedence is such that the leftmost assignment is executed last. The expression works like this:

```
if (new int[s] == nullptr) {
  throw std::bad_alloc();
} else {
  A = A;
}
```

The function never modifies `A`, and it immediately leaks the memory it allocates.

Comment: The bottom explanation really helped me understand what is going on in my use of the ternary operator. Thanks for the quick response, I supposed there is no way to correctly do what I was asking, or it is bad practice.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what it is you are asking, so I find it difficult to suggest the correct way of doing whatever that might be.

Comment: I wanted to make an `int *A` pointer. Then I will be setting it to a `nullptr` in the `main()` right after. I wanted to pass `A` into a function through a parameter along with a size, and return it by a ternary operator if it was successful allocating the size, if not throw the error. I just did not want to be returning a completely new `*A` dynamic array.

Comment: `A = new int[s];` would do that. `new` throws `bad_alloc` when it fails to allocate. On a related note, `_resize` is declared to return `int*`, but doesn't actually contain any `return` statement. Reaching the closing brace of a non-`void` function exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Comparing  `new int[s] == nullptr` should be pointless. It doesn't return `nullptr` on error, it throws `std::bad_alloc()`, IIRC.

Comment: @PSkocik thanks for the helpful information and working with me, it was great knowledge you shared. Also Igor.